# SQL : How to remove spaces from an int type row?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm inserting some data to a **database** and some of these data are **numbers** but have spaces in between like that **(37 64 73 92 34)** ***It's one integer not 5*** , The row that its type is **int** is not accepting these numbers and need it without spacing , So before inserting these numbers into the database I want to remove the spacing using **PHP** or **SQL** so the final result would be like that  **3764739234**.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are using.  Second, who what you want inserted into the database.  It is not clear what the final result should be.

Comment: You can use the `explode()` method creating an array of the numbers, then use a prepare statement to insert the data

Comment: these are NOT numbers in general meaning in IT, but strings

Comment: Sorry , It's one integer not 5 I edited the question , It's one integer with spaces and I want to remove the spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check if the number contains spaces, if it does then `explode()` the white spacing and put it back to an int using the `implode()` and `(int)` datatype force:

```
if(strpos($number, " ")) $number = (int) implode("", explode(" ", $number));
```

**See it working at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/4bZoF)**

Comment: @Sami, in PHP you do not to need to Datatype. As long as the value contains no white spacing then it will act as an int within the Query using PDO - you can insert a String into an INT column and it will work considering there is no white spacing and UTF-8 characters

Comment: @KDOT I'm not talking about PHP, your code is right, but how he will insert the bigint value to an INT column?

Comment: @Sami That is not a bigint value, an int value can be 255 characters long

Comment: @KDOT BigInt -> -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807), INT -> -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647), and in his example 3764739234.

Comment: If he is choosing to use an int column then the example will still work, yes.. it should be a big int but it still works as an int @Sami

Answer (score 1):

For MS SQL Server you can use `REPLACE()` function:

```
REPLACE('37 64 73 92 34', ' ', '');
```

The real issue is your number is `BigInt` not an `INT`, So you can do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,REPLACE('37 64 73 92 34', ' ', '') ) AS  [BigINTValue];
```

As you say in your question, ***The row that its type is int is not accepting these numbers***, that because you pass a `VARCHAR` to `INT` column, and you pass a `BigInt` to an `INT` column too. So, if you really need to store those values(`BigInt` datatype) , you need to `ALTER` your column to change the data type to `BigInt` datatype.

Comment: And if there is no spacing , What would happen ? , The integer changes dynamically so it could be with spacing or not

Comment: @Danny If there is no spaces, the function will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string "37 64 73 92 34" to be converted to "3764739234" (for example for telefon numbers without any special chars) you could use [*str_replace*](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php).

To get an *int* value from the string you can simply convert it like

```
    $newValue = (int) str_replace(" ", "", $inputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spacing in PHP you can simply use **str_replace**.

```
$your_number = '37 64 73 92 34'
$number_with_no_spaces = str_replace(' ', '', $your_number);
```

The code above replaces all the spaces (' ') with lack of char ('') in a given string ($your_number).

Comment: Code examples will help those who have been using PHP for sometime. I would suggest editing your answer to add an explanation for those who will not understand PHP and why you answer is better than the others given.